# Mostrar solo los últimos dos números del año

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Quisiera saber cómo hago una consulta en `SQL Server` para mostrar solo los últimos dígitos del año.

La consulta a la tabla para ver el año sería:

```
SELECT ano_vigencia FROM tabla WHERE codigo = 1
```

Esto me traería como resultado:

```
1 - 2020
2 - 2018 
3 - 2017
```

Pero yo quiero que se vean solo los últimos dos dígitos:

```
1 - 20 
2 - 18 
3 - 17
```

¿Cómo sería la consulta? Porque intenté esto:

```
SELECT Right(Cast(Year(tabla.ano_vigencia) As int),2) AS Año, ano_vigencia
FROM tabla WHERE codigo = 1
```

Pero el resultado fue el siguiente:

```
Año | ano_vigencia
05  | 2018
```

Comment: ¿El dato almacenado en `ano_vigencia` es exactamente así: `'1 - 2020'`?

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de dato es la columna `ano_vigencia`?

Comment: No, no, el dato almacenado es 2020
Yo añadí el `1 -` a modo de ejemplo para mostrar varios valores @jachguate

Comment: El tipo de dato es `int` @jachguate

Comment: El problema es si tienes años inferiores al 2000, si no fuere ese el caso, también podrías hacer `ano_vigencia - 2000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dado que el dato almacenado es entero, para obtener los últimos dos dígitos puedes aplicar el operador módulo `%` por cien.

```
select ano_vigencia%100 [año]
  from MiTabla
```

El operador módulo te devuelve el residuo de una división de enteros.

En 2018 dividido 100, el cociente es 20 (el resultado de la división) y el residuo es 18, que es la diferencia de 2018 - (20*100).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha sido de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion es que al `cast` de tu año lo conviertas a char(4) para despues se obtenga parte de la subcadena de 2 digitos.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT Right(Cast(Year(getdate()) As Char(4)),2)
```

tambien se puede aplicar directo el valor

```
SELECT Right(2020,2) en tu caso  SELECT Right(ano_vigencia,2)
```